# Freeradius doesn't execute scripts in exec module in daemon mode

Tags: freeradius

I'm stuck with Freeradius. Need to run a scripts with radius exec module. Everything works fine in debug mode (radius -X), but when I run it as a service in background it looks like exec service stop to work, nothing is execited, there is a permissions issue or there is a bug.
Here is more info on configuration in exec module.
Nothing special in **raddb/radiusd.conf**

```
modules {
$INCLUDE ${confdir}/modules/
...
$INCLUDE sites-enabled/
```

**raddb/module/exec**

```
exec exe_module {
wait = yes
program = "/bin/bash /var/testscript/test.sh %{User-Name} %{Framed-IP-Address} %{Acct-Status-Type}"
input_pairs = request
output_pairs = reply
shell_escape = yes
output = file
}
exec exe_module_stop {
wait = yes
program = "/bin/sh /var/testscript/test_delete.sh %{User-Name} %{Framed-IP-Address} %{Acct-Status-Type}"
input_pairs = request
output_pairs = reply
}
exec {
wait = yes
input_pairs = request
shell_escape = yes
output = none
```

}

**raddb/sites-available/default**

```
accounting {
detail
unix
radutmp
main_pool
sql
sql_log

if (Acct-Status-Type == Start) {
exe_module
}
if (Acct-Status-Type == Stop) {
exe_module_stop
}
attr_filter.accounting_response
}
```

Again everything works in debug when I run it as user. Once I start it as a service it doesn't  do anything. 
Please help! Pain 10 of 10

Answer (score 1):

In **freeradius/sites-enabled/default**, inside authorize{} section,
**authorize {
..
        update control {
           Auth-Type := `/etc/freeradius/radiusAuthentication.py %{Connect-Info} %{Filter-Id}`
     }
}**
try this to execute the external scripts in daemon mode.

Comment: Make sure your just echoes out the atrributes.Also your script should echo out Accept or Reject.

Comment: If you dont want to give Accept , then try printing 'ok' .So that , it wont take barely Accept.In the else part give, print 'Reject'.